# what are the key differences between CanvasJS and Vegalite?

Tags: graph, charts, vega-lite, canvasjs

I have been messing around with both CanvasJS and VegaLite for a little while now and for the most part, they seem extremely comparable to each other (feature-wise). Vegalite seems to have more artistic graphs at times but it seems like both can zoom, pan, sync, use tooltips and crosshairs...

for those who have used both somewhat extensively, what are the key feature differences you have noticed? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Similar to ggplot, Vega implements the Grammar of Graphics paradigm (see Leland Wilkinson). This means you can use basic building blocks to create virtually any data visualisation you want. This is in contrast to something like CanvasJS which suffers from what some call the "tyranny of charts" where you are limited to the chart types and options provided by the creator. The former requires more input from the user with more creative possibilities whilst the latter is probably much easier to use at the cost of being restricted to the options provided. There is some good background reading material here: https://medium.com/@mbostock/introducing-d3-scale-61980c51545f